# Is there a plugin that let you edit Posts and Comments in a front-end page?

Tags: editor

Basically, I need a plugin that let you edit posts and comments the same way you do in StackExchange sites (questions and replies)?

Because by default Wordpress sends you to the back-end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, try the [Front-end Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/) by Scribu!

Comment: @keatch that plugin is amazing. But it doesn't take you to another page, instead you edit in the same page.

Comment: Why would you want it to take you to another page?!

Comment: @scribu, is there any way of start editing by pressing a 'edit' link (instead of double clicking)?

Comment: See https://github.com/scribu/wp-front-end-editor/wiki/Tips-&-Tricks

Comment: @Scribu: Just took a look at your github wiki. As a sidenote: Wouldn't it make more sense if you don't _replace_ the actual content, but suggest that people add the editable content with a conditional tag like `if ( !current_user_can('edit_xy') && !is_plugin_active('editable_whatever_scribu') ) { // normal stuff } else { editable_whatever_fn(); }`. Btw: nice plugin!

Comment: Good idea, although the capability check is already done inside the template tag.